# stop image src changing on multiple images

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using:

```
$(function image_swap() {
    $('.mainthumb').click(function () {
        $('.main').attr('src', this.src.replace('-thumb', ''))
    });
});
```

to make my main image change to a different image when the thumbnail is clicked.

However there is more than one of these groupings on a single page (I.E one image with two smaller thumbnails underneath) as it is products listed down a page.

so product one has:

> main image with a class of main thumbnail image with class of
>   mainthumb and another thumbnail image with the class of main thumb

product two has

> main image with a class of main thumbnail image with class of
>   mainthumb and another thumbnail image with the class of main thumb

and so on.

So when i click a thumbnail of product one ALL the main images change to that thumbnails picture as they all have the same class - is there a way around this without have a different class for every product?

HTML:

> ```
>       <li><strong>Complete with:</strong></li>
>
>         <li>&bull; item 1</li>
>
>         <li>&bull; item 2</li>
>
>         <li>&bull; item 3</li>         
>
>     </ul> <img src="../images/image2-thumb.jpg" class="left mainthumb" />
>     <img src="../images/image3-thumb.jpg" class="left mainthumb" />
> ```

for some reason the html code edit isnt showing above that block of code the main image with the class of main

Comment: You might consider the user of $this here. If the instead of using the class name as selector. use $this construct.

Comment: `mainthumb` class is applied to what ?
can you give some html code or a fiddle that help a lot...

Comment: jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8AeHv/2/

Comment: why not give the complete code in fiddle ...

Answer (score 0):

You might consider the user of $this here. If the instead of using the class name as selector. use $this construct.

Assuming each of your main image is close to the thump nail group. So to find the nearest .main class element we can use closest

```
  $(function image_swap() { 
     $('.mainthumb').click(function (){
        $(this).prevAll('.main:first').attr('src', $(this).attr('src').replace('-thumb', ''));
     });
   });
```

This may not work perfectly but you need to think of various selectors like next(), previous() and find what best suits you.

Comment: @John can you place your HTML code as well, May be we could get you a better solution by looking into it.

Comment: @John Just made a quick change in my answer can you try the new code.

Comment: i have added the html but the it isnt showing at the very top of it: <img src="../images/image.jpg" class="left main" />

Comment: Cool I have tried your fiddle with alt attribute since image src was not available. http://jsfiddle.net/JHRkW/3/   Use prevAll('.main:first') and this will help you I have updated code above [not the fiddle] and this should work. Cheers!!

Comment: You must be copy pasting the code... did you try debugging it? did you try logging the $(this).prevAll('.main:first').attr('src') to console or alerting its value? how far you are success? see where you are going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Your html is a bit problematic there if you can surround the group of images with a `span` or a `div` following code can work

```
$('.mainthumb').click(function () {        
    $(this).parent().find('.main').attr('src', this.src.replace('-thumb', ''))
});
```

[**Check the demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mayekarsaurabh/8AeHv/3/)